# Automated build with Ant

Tags: java, maven, ant, build, continuous-integration

I am trying to perform automated build with Ant on a project. But the project  is using maven i.e pom.xml files instead of build.xml. So, how do i call those pom.xml files or represent them while building the project. Please help me out.

Comment: Why do you want to use ant instead of Maven to do the build?

Answer (score 0):

If you already has a pom.xml declaring the dependencies of your project you can use these declarations inside an ant script, via the [ant tasks](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/index.html).

After downloading the jar library, it goes like (all in your build.xml):

1. load the task definitions:

   `<taskdef resource="org/apache/maven/artifact/ant/antlib.xml">
       <classpath>
           <pathelement location="lib/build/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar"/>
       </classpath>
   </taskdef>`
2. load the pom using the `<pom>` task:

   `<pom id="pom_id" file="pom.xml"/>`
3. load filesets from the pom using `<dependencies>` task:

   `<dependencies filesetId="deps.compile" pomRefId="pom_id" useScope="compile"/>
   <dependencies filesetId="deps.test" pomRefId="pom_id" useScope="test"/>`